# Powershell strip computer name from dsquery

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to grab a list of all the computer names on my network and see if a directory exists on that PC in powershell, but I am having problems. Can someone look this over and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
$computers = dsquery computer "ou=TESTOU, dc=example, dc=com"
foreach($computer in $computers) {
    If(!(Test-Path -path "\\$computer.\C$\Program Files (x86)\Bit9\Parity Agent")) {
        Write-Host $computer
    }
    Out-File -FilePath .\result.txt
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default `dsquery computer` only returns the *DistinguishedName* for each computer, like so:

```
C:\>dsquery computer "ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com"
"CN=Computer01,ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com"
"CN=Computer02,ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com"
"CN=Computer03,ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com"
"CN=Computer04,ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com"
```

So, your `-path` argument becomes:

```
"\\CN=Computer01,ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com.\C$\Program Files (x86)\Bit9\Parity Agent"
```

Which is no good.

---

Use `dsquery * "ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com" -attr Name` to get the computers name instead, and parse it using `ConvertFrom-Csv`:

```
# Retrieve computer names
$Computers = dsquery * "ou=TESTOU,dc=example,dc=com" -filter "(objectClass=computer)" -attr Name -limit 0 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter " "

# Select only the name from the output
$Computers = $Computers | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name

# Assign any output from the foreach loop to $Results
$Results = foreach($Computer in $computers){
    $Path = '\\{0}\C$\Program Files (x86)\Bit9\Parity Agent' -f $Computer
    if(!(Test-Path -Path $Path)){
        # Don't use Write-Host, it only write text to the console
        $Computer
    }
}
# Write the computer names that failed to .\result.txt
$Results | Out-File -FilePath .\results.txt
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! So I seem to understand what the script is doing, so thats good, but one error did pop up. Its saying that -attr is an unknown parameter. I tried searching solutions to this, and the only one I found used dsget. Is there another way around this? Thanks man!

Comment: @AR917 Use `dsquery * -filter "(objectClass=computer)"` instead of `dsquery computer`

Comment: `the value of argument "name" is invalid`

I tried printing $Computers to see what it was printing out, but it didnt even get there

Comment: @AR917 Sorry, my dsquery-foo is a bit rusty, I usually go for the PowerShell AD Module when working with AD. Answer updated.

Comment: Does the version of powershell make a difference? I'm pretty sure I'm still on powershell 1.0. Will that affect it? As I'm still getting the name error

Comment: I'd try to upgrade PS if it's still on 1.0 since a lot of functionality has changed in 2.0 (and in 3 there are even more changes) If that's not possible try to use a machine that has a newer version.

Just get a "member PC" and upgrade to a newer version of PS to generate the list.

Comment: Yes, for instance, `ConvertFrom-Csv` doesn't work in v1.0 AFAIR

Comment: Okay, so I upgraded to V4.0, and now the output is: 

`WARNING: One or more headers were not specified. Default names starting with "H" have been used in place of any missing headers.
Test-Path : Access is denied`